# jquery: Loop through json array

Tags: jquery

I have an ajax call like this:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'assets/ajax/get-results.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: {}, 
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var obj = data[i];

          console.log(obj);
      }          
    }
  });
```

console.log(data) gives me:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
 0: {sum: 10, month: 'november', year: '2021', type: 'bezoeken'}
 1: {sum: 50, month: 'oktober', year: '2021', type: 'bezoeken'}
 length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

console.log(obj) split the array into 2 pieces:

```
{sum: 10, month: 'november', year: '2021', type: 'bezoeken'}
 month: "november"
 sum: 10
 type: "bezoeken"
 year: "2021"
[[Prototype]]: Object


{sum: 50, month: 'oktober', year: '2021', type: 'bezoeken'}
 month: "oktober"
 sum: 50
 type: "bezoeken"
 year: "2021"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

But want i want is a foreach on the month, year and type because i want to know what the sum is per month, year and type.
Because this data should be viewed in different HTML tables splitted per month.

[HTML table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFqW7.png)

Comment: Looks like what you've got is correct. Inside your loop, the value of `obj.sum` should be the sum. Might just be misunderstanding what the rest of your data could potentially look like though

Comment: What i have i correct, indead. But i have a HTML table with values dynamic build per month, so i need to know the sum per month, type and year

Comment: Ah, so you might have multiple rows for a specific month, year, or type?

Comment: it sounds like you want to access object properties and display them on one line?  this might help you get started:  `var year = data[i][‘year’]; var month= data[i][‘month’]; var type = data[i][‘type’];`.  Then you can concatenate those values in a string:  `console.log(“Year: ” + year + “, Month: ” + month)` etc.  i’m on mobile device, hope that helps.

Comment: I added a link to an image so you can see what i mean

Comment: What are the "1000, 2000, 3000..." headers representing? I don't see anything corresponding to that in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `data` is an `array` of `objects`, ie:

```js
var your_data = [
    {sum: 10, month: 'november', year: '2021', type: 'bezoeken'},
    {sum: 50, month: 'oktober', year: '2021', type: 'bezoeken'}
];
```

So if you want to:

- `iterate` over those `objects`
- access various `properties` of those `objects`

You can do something like:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < your_data.length; i++) {

    var year = your_data[i]['year']; 
    var month= your_data[i]['month']; 
    var type = your_data[i]['type'];
    var sum = your_data[i]['sum'];

    console.log("year: " + year + ", " + "month: " + month + ", " + "type: " + type + ", " + "sum: " + sum);
}
```

The above 'solution' is assuming your `data` is how you want it - ie you don't need to do any more aggregation on the year, month, type and sum from additional data.

In regards to getting those values into a table, there are many different ways you could do it.

Below is a simple example that may help you decide what you do, or don't, want in your solution.

Here is link to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/zeqv507d/) if you want to play around with it.

```js
var your_data = [{
    sum: 10,
    month: 'november',
    year: '2021',
    type: 'bezoeken'
  },
  {
    sum: 50,
    month: 'oktober',
    year: '2021',
    type: 'bezoeken'
  }
];

for (var i = 0; i < your_data.length; i++) {

  var year = your_data[i]['year'];
  var month = your_data[i]['month'];
  var type = your_data[i]['type'];
  var sum = your_data[i]['sum'];

  var row_html = `
        <tr>
            <td>${year}</td>
            <td>${month}</td>
            <td>${type}</td>
            <td>${sum}</td>
        </tr>
  `;

  $("#your_table").append(row_html);

}
```

```css
#my_table {
  border: 1px solid;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="your_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Sum</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user1063287, my question is solved.

```
for(var i = 0; i < your_data.length; i++) {

    var year = your_data[i]['year']; 
    var month= your_data[i]['month']; 
    var type = your_data[i]['type'];
    var sum = your_data[i]['sum'];

    console.log("year: " + year + ", " + "month: " + month + ", " + "type: " + 
    type + ", " + "sum: " + sum);
}
```